# How to buy Bitcoin in Iran

Tags: transactions, buy-bitcoins, deposit

So I'm trying to buy Bitcoin in Iran and I want to use my Iranian Bank Account which unfortunately isn't accepted by PayPal or other online payment websites.
So is there any way for me to buy Bitcoin(under one Bitcoin) using my Iranian Bank Account( Melli Bank or any other bank)?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

You will need to find an exchange that accepts your bank account or method of transferring from your account to the exchange.

A number of exchanges out there not personally sure which would accept your bank, but another option is Local Bitcoins

Here is the link for Iran https://localbitcoins.com/country/IR

UPDATE 1st June 2019: Local bitcoin is now banned due to new sanction.

Iranian can't use localbitcoin in Iran anymore but they can buy and sell here as an alternative: 
https://www.keepchange.io/buy/bitcoin/IRR?